# How to unit test Google Home functions?

Tags: unit-testing, actions-on-google, google-home

The way my Google Home app is organizaed is a class containing all intent methods and then

at the bottom a line

```
exports.myapp = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => new MyApp(request, response).run()
);
```

Since the functions in `MyApp` depend on `request` to get parameters from, I assume a unit test has to have a faked input `request` correct?

From the Actions On Google simulator, I've been able to get requests, but I'm not sure how to fake the response for the `response` parameter to `MyApp constructor, especially since the returning thing from Actions on Google seems to be after running my actual code.

All of the following would be helpful: generic code snippets, links to test files/cases, `request`/`response` constructor arguments, etc.

Thank you!

Comment: for reference, I am trying to use TDD Mocha, but that may be relatively unrelated

Comment: You can take a look at [some of the tests](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/tree/master/test) done in the library itself. If you have a mock of express objects, you may be able to simulate what the response should be.

Comment: Nick is right :) ...and in order to fake the response, you should take the code from: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/test/utils/mocking.js it's a good example for that.

Comment: I see, from the link posted by @IdoGreen, at line 80, where do I get that request from? It doesn't seem to be the same format as given by the Actions on Google Simulator, nor from the DialogFlow JSON request?